# Reset the current date in datepicker of ANTD on modal reopen in react js

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

**Problem**

After closing the modal the datepicker of antd not reset
If user select the date 2029/Feb/02 and close the modal after reopen the modal in datepicker selected year is 2029

**What I want**

After reopen the modal the today date would be selected

**What I tried**

According to doc
[Antd](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/) if defaultPickerValue is set then it should show the current date on modal reopen, but it's not working

```
defaultPickerValue={moment()}
```

**Code**

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fix-date-picker-inside-modal-window-in-react-js-forked-2z6wyb?file=/index.js:1303-1321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the initial state value to `undefined` instead of `""`. `defaultValue` will only set the value if the `value` prop is actually `undefined`.

EDIT: You also need to add `destroyOnClose` on the `Modal`. `defaultValue` is only set once when the component is mounted and since closing the modal is not actually unmounting the component, it will retain its state value.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fix-date-picker-inside-modal-window-in-react-js-forked-hcclx6?file=/index.js:707-716

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Sorry I missed one thing, have edited the answer and the code.

Comment: Only destroyOnClose needed, thanks